# User stories of current sprint number

Tags: python, rally

I a creating a dashboard for displaying user stories for all teams. That dash board should have current sprint user stories. I am writing a python script to call this.

This is how I am forming the Query string now. I am using Sprint number, team name and End date of the current sprint to get sprint user stories.

```
url     = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Project.Name%20%3D%20%22" + teamNameEncoded + "%22)%20and%20(Iteration.Name%20%3D%20%22Sprint%20" + key['sprintNumber'] + "%20" + key['sprintEndDate'] + "%22))&fetch=Name,FormattedID,PlanEstimate"
```

I am getting these values in an Json file.

**Json File**

```
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "sprintNumber": "114",
            "sprintEndDate": "Sep-19-2017",
            "teamName": "def",
            "filePath": "file1.json"
        },

        {
            "sprintNumber": "114",
            "sprintEndDate": "Sep-19-2017",
            "teamName": "abc",
            "filePath": "file2.json"
        }
]
}
```

**filePath** is to store the response.

So, How to get current sprint user stories based on current date (or) how might i use the API to get current sprint user stories without giving current sprint number and sprint end date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython?

Comment: No. I am new in creating API Query string, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a query like this:

```
((Iteration.StartDate < today) AND (Iteration.EndDate >= today))
```

There are some more tips and tricks about special queries in the help docs: https://help.rallydev.com/grid-queries